# How to override/patch hibernate class in grails app

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have application based on grails 2.2.4, it uses hibernate grails plugin:

BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {
  runtime ":hibernate:2.2.4"
  ...
}
```

which depends on hibernate 3.6.10.Final

I am facing weird NPE exception from AbstractFlushingEventListener internal hibernate class, same as here:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7867

So far I was unable to find root cause of the problem and now I would like to try to provide my own implementation of this hibernate class (copy paste of original class with some patching).

My naive attempt to create same package and class in my source code did not worked, grails is not picking it up.

Is it possible to do such override?
How do you do such things in grails app?

Comment: Since that version of hibernate does not get updates anymore because its old as stone (2012). You could fork the source, make your patch, and release a custom build of it just for your application. This could be easier than trying to override the class with your own implementation which should be possible with spring.